Next.js Hydration issues in my [slug].js blog component
I am trying to create a next.js post component but I keep getting hit with the below error and I don't know why - from what I can see I am using proper HTML nesting and sound structure.
I keep getting the same error code over and over again no matter what I do and I am using Next.js (15.0.0-canary.21)
import { gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import client from '../../lib/apolloClient';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Layout from '@/components/layout';
import parse from 'html-react-parser';

const GET_POST_BY_SLUG = gql`
  query GetPostBySlug($slug: String!) {
    postBy(slug: $slug) {
      id
      title
      content
      seo {
        fullHead
      }
      featuredImage {
        node {
          sourceUrl
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const MENU_QUERY = gql`
  query NewQuery {
    menu(id: "dGVybTo1") {
      menuItems {
        nodes {
          id
          label
          uri
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const PostPage = ({ initialPost, menu }) => {
  const { query: { slug }, isFallback } = useRouter();

  const { loading, data } = useQuery(GET_POST_BY_SLUG, {
    variables: { slug },
    skip: !slug,
    initialData: initialPost,
  });

  if (isFallback || loading) return <span>Loading...</span>;

  const post = data?.postBy || initialPost;
  const fullHead = post?.seo?.fullHead ? parse(post.seo.fullHead) : '';

  return (
    <Layout menu={menu} seo={fullHead}>
      {post?.featuredImage && (
        <div className="relative w-screen h-[60vh] mb-10">
          <Image
            src={post.featuredImage.node.sourceUrl}
            alt={post.title}
            fill
            style={{ objectFit: "cover" }}
            className="w-full h-full"
            priority
          />
          <div className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full bg-black opacity-50"></div>
          <h1 className="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 text-4xl text-white text-center">
            {post.title}
          </h1>
        </div>
      )}
      <div className='w-screen flex justify-center mt-10 mb-10'>
        <div className="text-poppins block mx-5 prose text-white w-screen" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content }}></div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query {
        posts {
          edges {
            node {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  });

  const paths = data.posts.edges.map(({ node: { slug } }) => ({ params: { slug } }));

  return { paths, fallback: true };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params: { slug } }) {
  const { data: postData } = await client.query({
    query: GET_POST_BY_SLUG,
    variables: { slug },
  });

  const { data: menuData } = await client.query({
    query: MENU_QUERY,
  });

  return {
    props: {
      initialPost: postData.postBy,
      menu: menuData.menu.menuItems.nodes,
    },
    revalidate: 10,
  };
}

export default PostPage;



Look like the improper usage of the dangerouslySetInnerHTML attribute in your JSX. This attribute is indeed used to inject raw HTML into your component, but it expects an object with a key __html containing the HTML string
used like this :

Hi can you show me an example please
